# Как написать цикл для вывода всех данных по шаблону?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unpivot

Имеется файл, содержащий данные:

[Файл с данными](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/G4JK/VSyKPdZ6W)

Требуется привести его к такому формату:

[image: Формат данных]

Как распространить его на все области?

Мой фрагмент кода:

```
first_row = vrp.iloc[[0]].T
area_name = ''
for i,j in first_row.iloc[0].items():
    area_name +=j
first_row = first_row.iloc[1:]
first_row['Область']=area_name
first_row
```

Этот код работает только для одной области. Что-то не могу сообразить, как это лучше сделать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [DataFrame.stack()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = pd.read_excel("2_vrp.xlsx", index_col=0)

res = df.stack().reset_index()
```

результат:

```
In [72]: res
Out[72]:
                         level_0 level_1         0
0           Белгородская область  1998г.  18245.50
1           Белгородская область  1999г.  32060.60
2           Белгородская область  2000г.  42074.50
3           Белгородская область  2001г.  49941.80
4           Белгородская область  2002г.  62404.40
...                          ...     ...       ...
1822  Чукотский автономный округ  2014г.  57751.30
1823  Чукотский автономный округ  2015г.  61735.50
1824  Чукотский автономный округ  2016г.  67704.80
1825  Чукотский автономный округ  2017г.  68242.63
1826  Чукотский автономный округ  2018г.  78143.40

[1827 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Ты чудо, спасибо большое!